# Need to use EF 4.1 when default is EF 4.3.1

Tags: entity-framework-4.1, nuget, entity-framework-4.3

I am running dev on VS2010 SP1, and when I run Install-Package EntityFramework, I get EF 4.3.1 installed by Nuget. Is there a way that I can restrict the version to EF 4.1? I would like to examine them differentially. Please help!

-Thanks,
Ram

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Nuget will install the latest version of a given package.

But you can install any previous version of a nuget package (which are available on nuget.org) within the [package manager console](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/using-the-package-manager-console#Installing_a_Package) specifying the [Version](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-manager-console-powershell-reference#Install-Package) option like:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 4.1.10715.0
```

You can check the available versions of EF [here](http://nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/4.3.1).

Answer (score 0):

Also, to see available versions for a package, enter in the console:
Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter entityframework (the name of the package)

Sagy

Comment: thanks! I guess there is an ocean in Nuget/Powershell that I am yet to explore! Thank you for the primer!